# Stuck on a dot product proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been stuck on this for hours and would really appreciate some help!

**Question:** Suppose $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a function that preserves dot products. In other words, for all $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $(u*v)=(\phi(u)*\phi(v))$. **Using only basic properties of dot product (such as the distributive law) and the definition of length:**

1. Prove that for all $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $|u+v|=|\phi(u)+\phi(v)|$.
2. Prove that for all $u,v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $|u+v-w|=|\phi(u)+\phi(v)-\phi(w)|$.

I can do these proofs in more complicated ways, but not with such simple assumptions! I'm not allowed to use the fact that $\phi$ is a linear operator, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to apply the definition of length, use linearity of dot product, and apply $\phi$ preserving dot product:

$|u + v|^2 = (u + v) \cdot (u + v) = u \cdot u + 2u \cdot v + v \cdot v = \phi(u) \cdot \phi(u) + 2\phi(u) \cdot \phi(v) + \phi(v) \cdot \phi(v) = (\phi(u) + \phi(v)) \cdot (\phi(u) + \phi(v)) = |\phi(u) + \phi(v)|^2$.

$|u + v - w|^2 = (u + v - w) \cdot (u + v - w) = u \cdot u + v \cdot v + w \cdot w + 2u \cdot v - 2u \cdot w - 2v \cdot w = \phi(u) \cdot \phi(u) + \phi(v) \cdot \phi(v) + \phi(w) \cdot \phi(w) + 2\phi(u) \cdot \phi(v) - 2\phi(u) \cdot \phi(w) - 2\phi(v) \cdot \phi(w) = (\phi(u) + \phi(v) - \phi(w)) \cdot (\phi(u) + \phi(v) - \phi(w)) = |\phi(u) + \phi(v) - \phi(w)|^2$.

When you see a question, think about how to make use of all the condition that it gives you, and that all it needs is some proper logic derivation to solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to show that $|u+v|^2=|\phi(u)+\phi(v)|^2$. Observe that  $$|u+v|^2=(u+v$*u+v)=(u*u)+2(u*v)+(v*v)$$
$$=(\phi(u)*\phi(u))+2(\phi(u)*\phi(v))+(\phi(v)*\phi(v))=$$ $$(\phi(u)+\phi(v)*\phi(u)+\phi(v))=|\phi(u)+\phi(v)|^2$$
The other one is similar..

Answer (score 1):

Should be straightforward expansion of the definition:
$$\begin{align}|u+v|&=\sqrt{(u+v)*(u+v)}\\&=\sqrt{u*u+v*u+u*v+v*v}\\&
=\sqrt{\phi(u)*\phi(u)+\phi(v)*\phi(u)+\phi(u)*\phi(v)+\phi(v)*\phi(v)}\\&
= \sqrt{(\phi(u)+\phi(v))*(\phi(u)+\phi(v))}\\&=|\phi(u)+\phi(v)|\end{align}$$
Similarly, for $|u+v-w|=\sqrt{(u+v-w)*(u+v-w)}$ we obtain a sum/difference of products of two vectors $\in\{u,v,w\}$ so that replacing these with $\phi(u),\phi(v),\phi(w)$ does not change the value and equals $\sqrt{(\phi(u)+\phi(v)-\phi(w))*(\phi(u)+\phi(v)-\phi(w))}=|\phi(u)+\phi(v)-\phi(w)|$.

The same method allows us to conclude more generally that $\left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_iu_i\right|= \left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\phi(u_i)\right|$ for any real coefficients $a_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my first solution was wrong. Here's a proper proof of 1.

$|\phi(u)+\phi(v)|^2 = (\phi(u)+\phi(v)) * (\phi(u)+\phi(v)) = \phi(u)*\phi(u) + 2\phi(u)*\phi(v) + \phi(v)*\phi(v) = u*u + 2u*v+v*v = (u+v)*(u+v) = |u+v|^2$

Thus $|\phi(u)+\phi(v)| = |u+v|,$ by the injectivity of the function $x \in [0,\infty) \mapsto x^2.$